# Should we consider MA(7)? How to interpret the ACF and pACF here?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, autocorrelation, covariance, acf-pacf

Getting very confused by these two plots. Can one from first `ACF` plot conclude that this is `MA(7)`? But why does the `pACF` look so messy?

```
acf(resid(my_mod, lag.max = 36, main ="ACF"))
```

[image: ACF plot]

```
pacf(resid(my_mod, lag.max = 36, main ="pACF"))
```

[image: pACF plot]